# What external dependencies do fat/assembly jars have?

Tags: scala, deployment, hive, sbt, thrift

So we're working on this Scala project with sbt and we had a a kind of a weird issue with fat jars

I created our fat jar (call it x.jar) on my local computer and ran some code that is using Hive JDBC to run some Hive queries on our Hive machine,  everything worked fine, however when I copied x.jar to another remote machine Y (not the Hive machine) and ran the code from there (connecting to the same Hive machine on the same port) it failed with a

```
java.sql.SQLException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

I used the word weird because I was under the impression that fat jars should not use any external dependencies but the result of what happened makes me re-think it

Both the machine and my computer are using the same Scala version. Since I used the same fat jar I don't think its a version collision issue

I also tried creating a new project from scratch and created a jar for it (not a fat jar) and then passed that jar to the Y machine and manually added the required jars as part of its classpath it successfully queried the Hive machine so I don't think its a connectivity issue either

So I've got 2 questions:

- Do fat jars use some kind of external dependencies? If so how is this determined? If not, could you help me think of a different explanation to the issue I mentioned?
- Could anyone recommend on any good reading material on regular jars vs fat jars? and when should you use each one?

Thanks

Comment: How did it fail? Generally as you say a fatjar bundles all library dependencies required. However, that doesn't mean it can't fail in some way. Plain Java (not even Scala!) example: You build your jar for Java 8 (by using new APIs from it or generating bytecode which targets 8) and run it on a server which only has Java 7 installed. Your application won't start or will eventually crash - fatjar or not.

Comment: I added some more information to the question so hopefully it will be more informative

Comment: SQLException, SocketTimeoutException sounds like something with your networking setup is off and you can't reach your Hive server. Definitely check your setup here, I doubt it's a code/build issue.

Comment: @alextsc I can reach that machine, also I created a new scala project that only uses hive jdbc and I created a jar for it (not a fat jar) and passed it to the machine, when I provided the hive jars as part of the classpath it worked from the same remote machine so I'm only guessing its not connectivity issues